# Jupyter Notebook and Modeling

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

So I am using Jupyter Notebook for my final project for this machine learning  class. This is the first time where I have to use multiple notebooks for an assignment.

In the first notebook, I created several regression models and used outlier detection, scaling, dimensionality reduction, and hyperparameters tuning for three different targets. I found the best three performing models for each target.

Now I need to deploy these models for any objective/task in the second notebook. Do I still need to do all of the steps (outlier detection, scaling, and dimensionality reduction) or can I just apply the models to the new dataset?

Comment: there should be function to save model and then you can read it in other notebook to recreate it and then you can use it without all this preprocessing. [9. Model persistence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)

Comment: Yes, you will need to apply all detection, scaling, and dimensionality reduction if you want to apply this model on new data. If all of these steps are in a [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) it should be a little easier.

Comment: @furas does it store the pca/outlier detection steps? or just the model hyperparameters?

Comment: If you use standard functions in sklearn for preperations then you could save their parameters also in pickle and it could recreate functions using data from pickle. But if you use non-standard methods then you will have to keep them as functions in other script file and import them to second script. [How to Save and Reuse Data Preparation Objects in Scikit-Learn](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-save-and-load-models-and-data-preparation-in-scikit-learn-for-later-use/)

Comment: and [Save and Load Machine Learning Models in Python with scikit-learn](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/)